# Contenttemplate-control doesn't fire

Tags: asp.net, controls

how exactly can I make control-events inside of a contenttemplate work? It's annoying enough that I can't access controls directly, but now the events don't even fire for whatever reason? I'm starting to hate webprogamming...

Front:

```
<act:TabContainer ID="tcTabellen" runat="server" TabIndex="0" AutoPostBack="true">
        <act:TabPanel ID="tpBeitragssaetze" HeaderText="Beitragss&auml;tze" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <p>
                    <asp:Label ID="lbKasse" runat="server">Kasse</asp:Label> 
                    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlKasse" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:Label ID="lbJahr" runat="server">Jahr</asp:Label>
                    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlJahr" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:DropDownList>
                </p>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </act:TabPanel>
</act:TabContainer>
```

Behind:

```
WithEvents ddlKasse As DropDownList
WithEvents ddlJahr As DropDownList

Private Sub ddlKasse_DataBind()
        ddlKasse = CType(Me.tcTabellen.FindControl("tpBeitragssaetze").FindControl("ddlKasse"), DropDownList)
        ddlKasse.AutoPostBack = True

        ddlKasse.Items.Clear()

        ddlKasse.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem With {.Text = "Bitte auswählen ...", .Value = "0"})
        ddlKasse.Items.Insert(1, New ListItem With {.Text = "01 - BKK Höchst (W)", .Value = "01"})
        ddlKasse.Items.Insert(2, New ListItem With {.Text = "02 - BKK Höchst (O)", .Value = "02"})
        ddlKasse.Items.Insert(3, New ListItem With {.Text = "10 - BKK Gesundheit (Alt) (W)", .Value = "10"})
        ddlKasse.Items.Insert(4, New ListItem With {.Text = "13 - Sancura BKK (W)", .Value = "13"})
        ddlKasse.Items.Insert(5, New ListItem With {.Text = "21 - DKV (W)", .Value = "21"})
        ddlKasse.Items.Insert(6, New ListItem With {.Text = "22 - DKV (O)", .Value = "22"})
        ddlKasse.Items.Insert(7, New ListItem With {.Text = "32 - BKK Vita-Dyckerhoff (W)", .Value = "32"})
        ddlKasse.Items.Insert(8, New ListItem With {.Text = "34 - BKK Gesundheit (W)", .Value = "34"})
        ddlKasse.Items.Insert(9, New ListItem With {.Text = "35 - BKK Gesundheit (O)", .Value = "35"})
        ddlKasse.Items.Insert(10, New ListItem With {.Text = "56 - STJB (W)", .Value = "56"})
        ddlKasse.Items.Insert(11, New ListItem With {.Text = "69 - BKK Bodensee + Südwest (W)", .Value = "69"})
        ddlKasse.Items.Insert(12, New ListItem With {.Text = "71 - STJB (O)", .Value = "71"})
        ddlKasse.Items.Insert(13, New ListItem With {.Text = "82 - BKK Vita Dyckerhoff (O)", .Value = "82"})
        ddlKasse.Items.Insert(14, New ListItem With {.Text = "83 - BKK Gesundheit (Alt) (O)", .Value = "83"})
        ddlKasse.Items.Insert(15, New ListItem With {.Text = "84 - Sankura BKK (O)", .Value = "84"})
        ddlKasse.Items.Insert(16, New ListItem With {.Text = "93 - BKK FPB Holding (W)", .Value = "93"})
    End Sub

Private Sub ddlKasse_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ddlKasse.SelectedIndexChanged
        ddlJahr_DataBind()
End Sub
```

I just want one ddl to be filled if the selectedindex of another one changes, but as I mentioned before .. the event doesn't fire. 
Does anybody have a clue what it is like that and how I can fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ddl needs the onselectedindexchanged on its tag:

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlKasse" onselectedindexchanged="ddlKasse_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: Doesn't work I get the following error: BC30456: "ddlKasse_SelectedIndexChanged" ist not a member of "ASP.modules_konti_tabellen_aspx".

Comment: Ah ok .. had to set the subs to protected, but now I get the error BC30455.

Comment: Aww .. had a () behind the sub as the value in onselectedindexchanged. Thanks for your help, dude.